# Set CPU Frequency on reboot

Tags: release-loki, cpu

Device - HP 23-q010e

Kernel - 4.4.0-64-generic

Heres what I've tried:

[No way to lock the CPU-frequency to a specific value](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4898/no-way-to-lock-the-cpu-frequency-to-a-specific-value)

The above link only talks about setting the cpu freq on the current boot, but if you reboot, your settings are back to default.  So I thought about going to Applications>System Settings>Applications>Startup and adding custom command:

```
cpupower -c all frequency-set --max 1.3ghz
/usr/bin/cpupower -c all frequency-set --max 1.3ghz
```

Neither one works.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/523640/how-i-can-disable-cpu-frequency-scaling-and-set-the-system-to-performance

I've also tried the above setting /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils.  No matter what I set the frequency to, doesn't work.

https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/11/09/how-to-set-cpu-governor-at-boot/

The above works great for Manjaro, but not Elementary OS.

I've also tried inserting the cpupower command into /etc/rc.local:

```
/usr/bin/cpupower -c all frequency-set --max 1.3ghz
cpupower -c all frequency-set --max 1.3ghz

exit 0
```

and

```
sh -c /home/ed/Documents/rclocal &;

exit 0
```

Maybe this is why rc.local doesn't work for Elementary OS:

```
Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

Please explain in lamen terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install TLP

```
 sudo apt install tlp
```

Then edit the config file - set the governor to powersave

```
 sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/default/tlp
```

Ensure the following lines are not commented and are as show below

CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=powersave
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=powersave

or

Try setting the CPU governor to performance. This will "lock" the CPU to max speed.

Install cpufrequtils

```
 sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

Then edit pr create the following file

```
 sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/default/cpufrequtils
```

And add the following line to it

```
 GOVERNOR="performance"
```

Save and exit

Then disable Ondemand daemon to keep your settings on reboot

```
 sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable
```

Check your settings with

```
 cpufreq-info
```

If this doesn't work for you, you can try what's listed [here](http://www.servernoobs.com/avoiding-cpu-speed-scaling-in-modern-linux-distributions-running-cpu-at-full-speed-tips/)

Comment: That worked for the governer, but what about frequency?  In that same file I've tried:  MAX_SPEED="1ghz" and MAX_SPEED="1000000".  To no avail.  I guess my question could be revised as this:  How to run an administrative command at startup.

Comment: With the governor set to Performance it will run your CPU at it's max freq all the time. Is that not what you are seeing when you run cpufreq-info?

Comment: Yes it is what I'm seeing.  The max frequency is 2.2ghz.  I don't want 2.2ghz I want 1.3ghz.  Ok so.. I tried to set it to powersave, which would make it run 1ghz only.  But the problem is, the file /etc/default/cpufrequtils does nothing.  The only thing that worked in what you said was this:  sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable.  Doing that disabled the ondemand which disabling the ondemand I guess the computer picks performance governer next by default.

Comment: Oh I see you don't want it locked at max. Sorry I misread. What you might try is installing TLP and editing the config file to force the powersave governor. I've had mixed results with that on eOS though but worth a shot.

Comment: BOOM, TLP is the answer.  Inside etc/default/tlp I changed  CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=1300000.  Now my frequency is 1.3ghz.  I was also able to change the governor here as well by CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=ondemand.  If you edit your answer I'll +1 you if I have enough points, if not then I can give you a check.  Thank you!!!!

Comment: Good to hear! My answer has been edited.